# Dijkstras Algorithmn Vue

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to implement dijkstras pathfinding algorithm in vue. I am following the psuedocode from https://medium.com/@nicholas.w.swift/easy-dijkstras-pathfinding-324a51eeb0f. This is what I have come up with so far, however I am struggling to translate the psuedocode into vue js. How would I be able to check every node and pop the visited nodes off the list?

```js
Dijkstra() {
      this.unexploredset = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++){
        for (let j = 0; j < 16; j++){
          this.nodes[i][j].position = '∞';
          this.nodes[i][j].distance = '∞';
          if(this.nodes[i][j].hasWall == false){
            this.unexploredset.push(this.nodes[i][j])
          }
        }
      }

      let current = this.nodes[3][4];
      let goal = this.nodes[14][14];
      for(let i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
        for (let k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
          if (current.distance <= current.neighbours[k].distance && current.unvisited == true)
          {
            current.unvisited = false;
            let temp = current.neighbours[k];
            current = temp
            this.unexploredset.pop(current);
            current = temp
            if (current == goal)
            {
              console.log("found");
              break
              
            }
            console.log(this.unexploredset.length)
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Do not translate it to Vue. Vue is responsible for display and behaviour of the website and it's really great at that. Vue is not for solving complex problems. Instead, adapt you algorithm so it is as abstract as possible and make your vue component call you pure-js object.

Comment: How would I use basic javascript in a vuejs file?

Comment: You can simply import it within <script> tags, same way you would import other components: `import MazeSolver from '@/services/maze-solver'` or wherever you put your object code (remember to use export as well!). You could then just build a new instance of solver (if you build as a constructor function) or directly as a function in one of the component methods.